# Allow users to post to a certain category

Tags: categories, users, cms

I have a website running Wordpress.

I have lots of content, e.g. tutorials, and I made a new category on a separate page, so I don't have a lot of content there. I want users to be able to add content *only* to my newly created category, even if they are subscribers.

I also want to be able to moderate everything they've posted to the category. Is that possible?

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

**[Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)** is a pretty good plugin to restrict category post access to users. It allows you to assign restrictions and roles to specific pages, posts or categories, which is what you said you need

Comment: Looks promising, but it's up to 2.9x only

Comment: Requires: 3.0 or higher
Compatible up to: 3.3.2

Comment: well, mine's 3.4.1 ;)

Comment: Well you'll see under Compatibility a user has said it works with 3.4.1

Comment: ok, I'll try it out! XD

Comment: @Nick did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use custom post type instead of a category. You can then create a post type with custom capabilities:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'custom',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
); 
register_post_type('book',$args);
```

Than you can use just Justin Tadlock's plugin Members to add the new capability type.

Comment: This is a clever solution too. Haven't thought about it this way.